# openssl ciphers command showing cipher as SSL not TLS

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm having issues with a application that is getting an SSL handshake error. The developers believe it's because we have the wrong ciphers on our server.  They are trying to use a cipher called TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.  From what I've found, the openssl name for this cipher is AES256-SHA.  When I list this cipher in openssl (I'm running openssl version 1.0.2k-fips) it's listed as an SSLv3 cipher:

```
0x00,0x35 - AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

Why would this be listed as SSLv3 and not TLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the ciphers command in OpenSSL shows you the minimum SSL/TLS version that a ciphersuite is compatible with. That particular ciphersuite is compatible with all SSL/TLS versions from SSLv3 up to TLSv1.2.

Comment: makes sense.  Thanks.  Where can I get a list of the SSL/TLS versions that a particular ciphersuite is compatable with?

Comment: A complete list of all ciphersuites that OpenSSL supports is available with `openssl ciphers -v ALL:eNULL`. If you have OpenSSL 1.1.0 or above then you can also pass the `-stdname` option which will give you the standard name, as well as the OpenSSL name. You can also look at the IANA ciphersuite registry at https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4. This is a list of all ciphersuites that have ever been defined cross referenced against the RFCs that defined them. You'd have to check the RFCs though to see what protocol versions they can be used with